# Print the selected week from a Calendar control on a label.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to print the selected week from a calendar control on a label. The selected week will be from Monday to Sunday. It has to look something like this: 2015-09-29 - 2015-10-04. Thanks in advance for the help!

Below is the code that I have tried so far, but this code only prints each respective date of that week.

```
        DateTime input = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
        int delta = DayOfWeek.Sunday - input.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime firstDay = input.AddDays(delta);

        Label3.Text = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            Label3.Text += ((DateTime)(firstDay.Add(new TimeSpan(i, 0, 0, 0)))).ToShortDateString() + "  ";
```

Comment: What is it you're choosing in the calendar control? Is it just a single date?

Comment: No, you choose the Monday to Sunday of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Since Sunday has the index of 0, and you want the week to start from Monday,
// we need to shift the numbers around so that Monday is 0 instead.
int dayNumber = ((int)Calendar1.SelectedDate.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;

DateTime monday = Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(-dayNumber);
DateTime sunday = Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(6 - dayNumber);

Label3.Text = string.Format(
    "{0} - {1}",
    monday.ToShortDateString(),
    sunday.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!